# How to import sqlite from plain text dump?

Tags: import, sqlite, dump

[This excellent XKCD article](https://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results) about color-poll data at the very end mentions:

> If you have ideas and want to analyze these results further, I’ve posted the raw data as an SQLite dump [here](http://xkcd.com/color/colorsurvey.tar.gz) (84 MB .tar.gz file).

In the archive you will find plain .TXT file `mainsurvey_sqldump.txt` which is SQLite dump. I work on MAC and would like to turn this dump into a database. **How can I do it and what friendly software can I use?** I am very beginner at SQLite and DB. I tried **DB Browser for SQLite** (at `sqlitebrowser.org`) but could not figure out how to import the dump (what I tried runs forever).

Thank you very much for any tips.